# Multivariable Function. Differentiable $\Rightarrow$ Partial Differentiable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I cannot understand why this proposition holds. Let

- $U$ be an open set in $\Bbb R^{n+m}(=\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m)$,
- $f$ : $U\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a function,
- $x_0 \in \Bbb R^n, y_0 \in \Bbb R^m,$ be two points such that $(x_0,y_0)\in U$.

Then we can pick up a neighbourhood $V$ of $x_0$, and define
$g : V \to \mathbb{R}^d$ as
$$
g(x):=f(x,y_0).
$$
If $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)(=:z_0)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\|f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)-Df(z_0)h\|}{\|h\|}=0
\end{equation}
holds,
then $g$ is differentiable, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\exists A \ (\text{a $d\times n$  matrix}) \ ; \
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\|g(x+h)-g(x)-Ah\|}{\|h\|}=0
\end{equation}
holds (In other words, $f$ is partial differentiable about $x$ at $(x_0,y_0)$).

I have no idea to prove this. 
Maybe I have to evaluate the quantity
$$\dfrac{\|g(x+h)-g(x)-\square h\|}{\|h\|}
$$
but I don't know what $\square$ is.

I would like you to tell me some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specialize your $h$. Choose $h=(k_1,k_2,\dots k_n,0,0,\dots 0)$ where there are $m$ zeroes. Call $k=(k_1,k_2,\dots k_n)$. Observe that $g(x)=f(x,y_0)$ and $g(x_0+k)=f(z_0+h)$. Using the definition of differentiability of $f$ at $z_0$ you get
$$
\frac{\|g(x_0+k)-g(x_0)-Ak\|}{\|k\|}\to 0
$$
where $k$ is arbitrary and $A$ is the sub matrix of $D$ consisting of the first $n$ columns of the matrix $D$. Therefore, $g$ is differentiable at the point $x_0$ and its Jacobian matrix is $A$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your explanation.